# Whats the performance of 10000 clients pulling every 5,3,1 sec vs keeping a websocket connection

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

Given 10000 clients, what will be most demanding for the webserver (signalr and aspnet core on kestrel) to

1. Answer normal rest api get requests (5,3,1 sec in between calls) (token pointer on query string to tell what data it already have received and if equal latest pointer, its a noop)
2. Maintaining websocket connections and only push when data is updated

Lets assume that it is also a nooop to retrieve the data from the store in both examples, so the question is just about websockets vs requests.

if these 10000 clients was mobile devices - what will demand the most power to get the data? Keeping a websocket open or to pull the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to balance is cost of connectivity vs cost of data transfer.

In case of 10000 clients with updates coming at 5,3,1 per second you will better be with web-sockets as there is less amount of server processing per request and once initialized it will be good to transfer data over the established connection per client.

Websocket wont be taking resources as http does when connected and disconnected and it also saves bandwidth in your case.